# How to run command in Perl without sudo?

Tags: perl, sudo

I have problematic use case:

I run Perl script with `sudo` (from Jenkins):

> sudo /usr/bin/perl /Users/snaggs/scripts/build_ios.pl ${BUILD_NUMBER}
>   $Version $isPublish

The script runs several commands from CLI.

one of them is: `$ pod spec lint` that fails with error: `Cannot run pod as root`.

```
my $command = "/usr/local/bin/pod spec lint $POD_SPEC_FILE_ABS --verbose";      
my $podResults = `$command`;
```

I don't want to remove `sudo`.

How can I run specific command into the script without super user?

Answer (score 3):

You should use sudo  `my $command = "sudo -u $username /usr/local/bin/pod spec lint $POD_SPEC_FILE_ABS --verbose";`

Answer (score 2):

From `man sudo`:

> sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] **[-u user]**

Use the `-u` flag to specify a user who isn't the superuser but has the permissions needed to do what you want to do.

---

I wouldn't want Jenkins running test code as a regular user though (nor as the super user).

A better approach would be to set the ownership and permissions of the files and directories that Jenkins needs to access to grant permission using a *group*, make Jenkins run as a member of that group, and then remove `sudo`.